# How to create a compound index in MongoDB through Java driver?

Tags: java, mongodb, indexing, mongodb-java

I want to create compound index on `Age` and `Name`  in MongoDB through Java driver and here is my syntax:

```
coll.ensureIndex(new BasicDBObject("Age", 1),new BasicDBObject("Name", -1));
List <DBObject> list = coll.getIndexInfo();

  for (DBObject o : list) {
       System.out.println(o);
    }
```

but it create only  1 index not compund index and give me result this:

```
{ "v" : 1 , "key" : { "_id" : 1} ,"ns" :"EmployeeData.EmpPersonalData", "name":"_id_"}
{ "v" : 1 , "key" : { "Age" : 1} , "ns" : "EmployeeData.EmpPersonalData" , "name" : "Age_1" , "Name" : -1}
```

So how can compund index on collection can be created through java driver?

Answer (score 27):

If you look at your code, you have actually called `ensureIndex` with two parameters. Your first parameter was the key and your second parameter became some extra field: `Name: -1`.

What you are looking to pass in the first parameter is this object `{"Age":1, "Name":-1}`. What you actually passed was `{"Age":1}, {"Name":-1}`.

So you want to do something like this:

```
BasicDBObject obj = new BasicDBObject();
obj.put("Age", 1);
obj.put("Name", -1);
coll.ensureIndex(obj);
```

Note that the index will be created with a default name. To provide a specific name do the following:

```
coll.ensureIndex(obj, "MyName");
```

Comment: In Stackoverflow, I get points if you mark the answer as correct and/or vote it up. It also tells other people that this was the correct answer. Would you be able to do that?

Comment: why not @Gates ! sorry i must have done before but i am new to this site :)

Answer (score 5):

You can try this according to the official documentation.

```
import org.bson.Document;
db.getCollection("restaurants").createIndex(new Document("cuisine", 1).append("address.zipcode", -1));
```

[Official Mongo DB Driver Java documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/java/indexes/)

Answer (score 4):

A more modern and perhaps fluent approach could be:

```
import com.mongodb.client.model.Indexes;

collection
    .createIndex(
        Indexes.compoundIndex(
            Indexes.ascending("Age"),
            Indexes.descending("Name")
        )
    );
```

Found in [the manual](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.5/driver/tutorials/indexes/#compound-indexes).  Formatted for clarity; post-format to your own taste.